# Unable to deserialize Json in response class

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning

I have below JSON I need to deserialize this in response class

```
{
    "resource": {
        "revision": {
            "id": 44,
            "rev": 28,
            "fields": {
                "System.AreaPath": "DemovR V2",
                "System.TeamProject": "DemovR V2",
                "System.IterationPath": "DemovR V2"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My response class

```
public class getUpdatedEvent
    {
        public cls_resource resource;
    }
    public class cls_resource {
        cls_revision revision;
    }
     class cls_revision {
        public Integer id;  //44
        public Integer rev; //28
        public cls_fields fields;
    }
    class cls_fields {
        object fields;
        }
```

getting error

> System.JSONException: Apex Type unsupported in JSON: Object

whereas it is working without response class what I tried so far.

```
PayLoad__c pl = [select Load__c from PayLoad__c limit 1];
Map<String, Object> res_map =(Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(pl.Load__c);
Map<String, Object> reso = (Map<String, Object>) res_map.get('resource');
Map<String, Object> reso_fields = (Map<String, Object>) reso.get('revision');
Map<String, Object> fields = (Map<String, Object>) reso_fields.get('fields');
system.debug('-fields-'+fields.get('System.AreaPath'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is more likely to work if you change the class to:

```
class cls_fields {
    Map<String, String> fields;
}
```

and perhaps also:

```
Map<String, String> fields = (Map<String, String>) reso_fields.get('fields');
```

**PS**

Your `JSON.deserializeUntyped` approach looks like the only way to go based on your comments. You can write code to transfer the data into your classes, if you need all the information to be conveniently accessible.

Comment: What if we get integer or another data type?

Comment: Then yes declare as Map<String, Object> and cast.

Comment: It's not working, throwing error `Apex Type unsupported in JSON: Object`

Comment: My bad. I'll add an alternative answer.